# __init__ method for form with additional arguments

Tags: python, django, django-forms, initialization

I'm calling my form, with additional parameter 'validate :

`form = MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES, validate=True)`

How should I write form's **init** method to have access to this parameter inside body of my form (for example in _clean method) ? This is what I came up with :

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        validate = args['validate']
    except:
        pass           
    if not validate:
        self.validate = False
    elif:
        self.validate = True
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `validate=True` argument is a keyword argument, so it will show up in the `kwargs`dict. (Only positional arguments show up in `args`.)

You can use [kwargs.pop](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop) to try to get the value of `kwargs['validate']`.
If `validate` is a key in `kwargs`, then `kwargs.pop('validate')` will return the associated value. It also has the nice benefit of removing the `'validate'` key from the `kwargs` dict, which makes it ready for the call to `__init__`.

If the `validate` key is not in `kwargs`, then `False` is returned.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.validate = kwargs.pop('validate',False)
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you do not wish to remove the `'validate'` key from `kwargs` before passing it to `__init__`, simply change `pop` to `get`.